# Does Adrien Brody's Character in "Restaurant" (1998) Use the N-Word?

Tags: dialogue, restaurant

Towards the end of the 1998 movie "Restaurant" ([imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0152176/), [a good NYT review](http://www.nytimes.com/library/film/012800restaurant-film-review.html)) with Adrien Brody, his character Chris is having an altercation evolving into a fight with a young black co-worker (played, I think, by Avery Kidd Waddell). The scene is pivotal in the movie. It's an outbreak of racially tainted hostility which comes unexpected particularily for Chris' friends (and possibly himself). After the fight everybody looks at him as if seeing a different man.

I have viewed the scene a few times because I was curious what exactly he said during the altercation. The scene does not appear to be online anywhere, unfortunately, so I cannot link to it.

On the DVD I have (Digiview Entertainment #TEX65M), one hears him say "Motherf..." which to me doesn't seem to warrant the stunned reaction of his friends. Given that there was a blurring of a "finger" gesture in another scene, and possibly one or two other places where an expletive was replaced, is it conceivable that he actually used the N-word but that it was later dubbed over? Were these edits done for the home video version only (thanks to cde for pointing that out)?

Comment: Vote to close because it's purely speculation.  Unless someone can find a canon answer, which isn't likely.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Well, I saw two possibilities for more information: A native speaker may be a better lip reader; or there may even be some story about it. Of course it's a long shot to hope for that. If other people wondered as well, I'd be interested in that too.

Comment: An obscure answer is not a valid reason to VTC this as opinion based. Down vote any speculative answer instead. This is a valid question. Even further, the question asks "Was this censored on home release compared to Theatrical"

Comment: @cde You are right that probably the cinematic version had the finger un-blurred. The editors may have altered language as well.  That didn't even occur to me since I was so fixated on the DVD. But it would be hard for anybody without eidetic memory to recall these details after so many years.

Comment: Would this be censored in foreign versions? I'd try to get a European version with original language and watch it to be sure. They wouldn't blur a finger or make a scene more PC in Europe, especially if what he says is important to the plot.